# UITableViewCell - Updating NSMutableDictionary Values

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have UITableViewController and it has twitter like post with like buttons. what im doing is when ever like button clicked if it is success trying to update the like count by + 1. i did the all the the above method except for the update part.
im getting `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'` Error.

Here is my code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    FeedTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    NSDictionary *feedList = [liveFeeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//liveFeeds is NSMutableArray

cell.likeCount.text = [feedList objectForKey:@"likes"];
cell.like.tag = indexPath.row;

    [cell.like addTarget:self action:@selector(likeClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

-(void) likeClicked:(UIButton*)sender{

//Here im using AFNetworking and getting JSON response.
//After that im doing following to update the like

NSMutableDictionary* feedList = [liveFeeds objectAtIndex:sender.tag];

            NSString *oldLike = [feedList objectForKey:@"likes"];
            int newLike = [oldLike intValue] + 1;
            NSString *strFromInt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",newLike];

            NSLog(@"updated like %@",strFromInt); // up to this it works

            [feedList setObject:strFromInt forKey:@"likes"]; // in here it get crashe

            [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

What i want to do is. `liveFeeds` Array update with that Like Count and reload the table.  am i doing this wrong? or is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: If you are updating data that was originally parsed from a JSON, you can just pass `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` or `NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves`, otherwise you will have to convert the `liveFeeds` array to contain `NSMutableDictionary` instead of `NSDictionary`.

Comment: @Sulthan can you tell me how to do that. any link similar to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely `[liveFeeds objectAtIndex:sender.tag]` is a `NSDictionary`, not an `NSMutableDictionary`. So you cannot change its content.

Build feedlist with the content of `[liveFeeds objectAtIndex:sender.tag]` :

```
NSMutableDictionary* feedlist = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[liveFeeds objectAtIndex:sender.tag]]
```

Comment: `mutableCopy` is a simpler solution to create a mutable dictionary (`[liveFeeds[sender.tag] mutableCopy]`). The problem is, it also needs to be saved back into `liveFeeds[sender.tag]` which must be a `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: Ah. its not crashing now. now i want to assign this Dictionary back to `liveFeeds` array and reload table. i think my thinking is correct. is it?

Comment: Yep. Like Sulthan already said: You have to save it back to your `liveFeeds`. Therefore (same logic), `liveFeeds` has to be a `NSMutableArray`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it yet but i guess you're trying to use a NSMutableDictionary method on a NSDictionary.
Try changing:

```
NSMutableDictionary* feedList = [liveFeeds objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
```

To:

`NSDictionary* dic = [liveFeeds objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
NSMutableDictionary* feedList = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:dic]];`

Answer (score 1):

Simply create mutable copy of NSDictionary. Actually `NSMutableDictionary* feedList = [liveFeeds objectAtIndex:sender.tag]` returns `NSDictionary`. So to make it editable you have to create another copy which is mutable by using `mutableCopy`. `NSMutableDictionary* feedList = [[liveFeeds objectAtIndex:sender.tag]mutableCopy]`

```
 -(void) likeClicked:(UIButton*)sender{

 //Here im using AFNetworking and getting JSON response.
 //After that im doing following to update the like

       NSMutableDictionary* feedList = [[liveFeeds objectAtIndex:sender.tag]mutableCopy];

        NSString *oldLike = [feedList objectForKey:@"likes"];
        int newLike = [oldLike intValue] + 1;
        NSString *strFromInt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",newLike];

        NSLog(@"updated like %@",strFromInt); // up to this it works

        [feedList setObject:strFromInt forKey:@"likes"]; // in here it get crashe

        [self.tableView reloadData];

 }
```